# How to pass inherited types in generic methods

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a generic method which takes in an `Event` inherited type (e.g. `MouseMoveEvent`) and a function to execute based on if the local event matches the type of the event passed as `TEvent`

```
public bool Dispatch<TEvent>(TEvent e, Func<TEvent, bool> func) where TEvent : Event
        {
            if (_event.GetEventType() == e.GetEventType())
            {
                Event.Handled = func(e);
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
```

```
public void OnEvent(Event e)
{
    EventDispatcher dispatcher = new EventDispatcher(e);
    dispatcher.Dispatch<MouseMoveEvent>(e, OnCloseWindow);
}
```

When I try to call the method, VS gives me the error "Cannot convert from `MouseMoveEvent` to `Event`". This makes sense to me, as the `TEvent` type needs to be the same. I guess I'm asking if there is any way I can pass the `Event` in seeing as `MouseMoveEvent` inherits `Event`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by changing the method from

```
public bool Dispatch<TEvent>(TEvent e, Func<TEvent, bool> func) where TEvent : Event
        {
            if (_event.GetEventType() == e.GetEventType())
            {
                Event.Handled = func(e);
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
```

to

```
public bool Dispatch<TEvent>(Event e, Func<TEvent, bool> func) where TEvent : Event
        {
            if (e is TEvent && Event.GetEventType() == e.GetEventType())
            {
                Event.Handled = func(e as TEvent);
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

options:

If it doesn't matter that `T` is specifically `MouseMoveEvent`:

- `dispatcher.Dispatch<Event>(e, OnCloseWindow);`
- `dispatcher.Dispatch(e, OnCloseWindow);` (implicit)

If it matters, and `e` *actually is* a `MouseMoveEvent`:

- `dispatcher.Dispatch<MouseMoveEvent>((MouseMoveEvent)e, OnCloseWindow);` (cast)
- `dispatcher.Dispatch((MouseMoveEvent)e, OnCloseWindow);` (implicit and cast)

If it matters, and you don't know, perhaps test:

```cs
if (e is MouseMoveEvent mme)
{
   // more specific, with mme
}
else
{
  // less specific, with e
}
```

Comment: It does matter that `e` is a `MouseMoveEvent`. Your third option is what I thought would work but when `e` is not a `MouseMoveEvent`, it throws an `InvalidCastException`

Comment: @BeckamWhite `is` operator won't throw any exception, unless you did something wrong

Comment: I was also trying to avoid type-checking like in your answer to make the code a little bit more readable but I guess im going to have to sacrifice that for it to work.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski yeah, I was trying to avoid type checking though for readability

Comment: @BeckamWhite type checking can also often be avoided through polymorphism - maybe some `virtual void Foo()` on the base type?